# Random Multiple image rotator - display a screen of images randomly when page refreshed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, random, rotation

I am in need of a multiple random image rotator.

I have a full page of multiple 120px X 100px logos across the whole screen, what i want to do is when the page is refreshed the logos rotate around the screen randomly, so one logo is not in the same position all the time.

Also It cant duplicate the logos, therefore the logo cannot be repeated on the screen?

Can anyone help me here?

I thought it might be as simple as a bit of jQuery giving the div that all the logo's are contained in a class, then when refreshed it just mixes them all up randomly?

Every tutorial i have tired only takes into consideration ONE image being displayed on the screen!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use some random numbers to move the elements around.

Javascript's Math.random will do fine for this, then iterate over all the images and move them around a bit on page load.

Here's a really simple example:

```
$('.images').each(function() {
    randomElm = $('.images').get(Math.floor(Math.random()*10));
    randomElm.parentNode.insertBefore(this, randomElm);
});
```

Here's a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/38Jg5/1/)

Comment: This sounds perfect, thanks, but i cant get it to work at all for my site: - http://adoogle.co.uk/full-random.html any ideas why?? Thanks

Comment: anyone know why it might not work with the code on my site? When i refresh the images disappear and i just get the loading icon?? thanks

Comment: I really have no idea, could be that the images are not loaded when the function is called, or could be a lot of other things? The code is just meant as a general example of how to select random elements, and you will have to make it fit your particular makeup etc.

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">
(function($){
$.fn.shuffle = function() {
var allElems = this.get(),
getRandom = function(max) {
return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
},
shuffled = $.map(allElems, function(){
var random = getRandom(allElems.length),
randEl = $(allElems[random]).clone(true)[0];
allElems.splice(random, 1);
return randEl;
});
this.each(function(i){
$(this).replaceWith($(shuffled[i]));
});
return $(shuffled);
};
})(jQuery);
$(function() {
$(".images").shuffle();
});
</script>`